# Laravel 5 homestead phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

Recently I successfully installed laravels homestead VM. Now I want access to my db via PhpMyAdmin, ideally my PhpMyAdmin from my localhost setup (XAMPP).
Is this possible?

I've came across [an article](https://gist.github.com/ratiw/71974928337fd3a1fe24) that's stated I can install phpmyadmin in my ubuntu VM but when I destroy the VM I need to reinstall PMA over and over.

Is there any way I can have a UI for databases in de VM homestead?

Comment: why do you destroy the VM ? can you simply halt and restart ? also if you really need you could customize the after.sh shell script from homestead to add the PMA install so even in case of destroy, next up would install PMA as well

Comment: @frederic Thanks for your response. That's also an option aswel, I don't like halting VMs since its quite exausting for my poor CPU, i guess..? But I would like to know also if its possible to access database on XAMPP on my VM?

Comment: no, halting the VM stops the process so there's nothing running on the host after VM is halted

Comment: Allright thanks for the tip, I'll just suspend my VM for now, though I would like to know how to access phpmyadmin on localhost (XAMPP) if its possible...

Answer (score 0):

By default PhpMyAdmin runs on port `8000` so make sure to forward the port so you can access it from your host

1. either from `Vagrantfile` directly config.vm.network, add the following line

   ```
   "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
   ```
2. or you can update `Homestead.yaml' and add the following

   ```
   ports:
       - send: 8000
         to: 8000
   ```